# Python is not finding module in virtual environment anymore on command line

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I created a virtual environment with `venv` and installed `flask_sqlalchemy` with it. But if I run `source venv/bin/activate`, so that I am now running in the virtual environment, Python can't find the module. In particular, I type `python3` and then `import flask_sqlalchemy` into the comand line, and I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

But I *am* running inside the virtual environment, I'm pretty sure, because when I do `os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']`, I get my virtual environment directory. (However, I will note that if I use `hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix')`, I get `False`, so I'm not totally sure what's going on there.

I'm really not sure why this isn't working, since everything was working on command line just a couple of days ago. It seems somehow as though command-line Python isn't running with the right interpreter (my linter, or whatever it is that checks for errors in code, on VSCode isn't throwing any errors, and if I run the actual Flask app, nothing goes wrong). I don't really understand what that means though, or how to fix it. I found a lot of discussion online about Python paths, but I still don't get them, and I'm not entirely sure if that's what is going wrong here.

Comment: have you tried deleting and recreating your venv?

Comment: If you are using linux, what is the output of `which python3` ? What command you used to installed *flask_sqlalchemy* in venv?

Comment: One of the top causes of this is using a different python than the one the virtualenv expects. With the virtual environment activated, `python` will get you the right one. `python3` risks getting the wrong one.

Comment: @AkibRhast I haven't deleted/recreated my venv, and I'd prefer not to, but I'll give that a shot if we can't figure out what's going on!

Comment: @isAif I'm using a mac, but the output is ```/usr/local/bin/python3``` (huh...not the venv, is that something to worry about?). I used ```pip3``` (my shell is zsh and doesn't recognize pip...or something along those lines, I'm not super sure)

Comment: @DaveW.Smith Hmm, so ``python``` actually gives me the worse error of not being able to find the ```flask``` module (I guess because all my packages are stored in my python 3 site packages folder, and I can't even use ```pip``` anymore to download as python 2)

Comment: As @DaveW.Smith said you should be using `python` instead of `python3` as venv will use the correct python once you have created the *virtual environment*, you can check this by using `which python` and `which pip`, this will show you the version used by *venv*. First activate venv and then use `pip` to install whatever package you need and `python` to execute python commands.

Comment: With the virtual environment activated, `pip install` will install into the virtual environment. If you happened to do `pip3 install`, then you installed outside the environment. It might pay to take a look though `venv/lib/python*/site-packages` to see what's actually installed there.

Comment: Okay, thanks, everyone! So what worked for me was to use a bash shell (instead of zsh), and to use pip (as you all suggested I do). The odd thing was that I did check my venv site-packages folder before using pip, and it contained all the folders I wanted it to. But it was only after using pip that things started working.